# Before fully loading page loading bar is hided in jsf

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, xhtml

Actually I am getting loading bar but before page content get loaded loading bar is hided. I want loading bar until page is not loaded correctly.

Below code I have used in layout.xhtml

```
 <li class="#{loginBean.subMenu eq 'Booking_History' ? 'active' : ''}">
          <p:commandLink rendered="#{loginBean.logedadmin or loginBean.logedagent}" action="#{bookingHistoryBean.showList}" value="Booking History"
                        immediate="true">
                        </p:commandLink>
```

java method

```
public String showList() {
    startLoadingBar();
    status="All";
    noOfRecords=0;
    getList();
    searchBookingHistory();
    log.info("Loaded successfully");
    return "/pages/internalstackholders/bookinghistory.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

In bookinghistory.xhtml

```
 <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" id="statusbar" modal="true"
        showEffect="fade" showHeader="false" closable="false" width="250"
        resizable="false">
    <h:form>
      <center>
        <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/loading.gif" /><br />
        <b>Please wait...</b><br />
        <br />
      </center>
    </h:form>
  </p:dialog>
```

Any body having any suggestion.

Comment: suggestion: create a [mcve]. Cannot see anything in your code related to the title/issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer..

In layout.xhtml I have added below code inside body.

```
<div id="nonAjaxLoad">
    <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/loading.gif"/>
</div>
```

Then I have added script code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("ready is called");
    //PF('statusDialog').hide()
    $('#nonAjaxLoad').hide();
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
     console.log("bind is called");
    // PF('statusDialog').show()
    $('#nonAjaxLoad').show(); 
});
</script>
```

And I have added in css

```
#nonAjaxLoad {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position:absolute;
bottom: 50%;
right: 50%;
z-index: 999
}
```

Now loading bar is working correctly. I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995661/5333146).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code it works for me 
onclick="statusDialog.start()" and  oncomplete="statusDialog.close()"

```
    <p:commandButton rendered="#{loginBean.logedadmin or loginBean.logedagent}" action="#{bookingHistoryBean.showList}" value="Booking History" immediate="true" async="true" onclick="statusDialog.start()" oncomplete="statusDialog.close()" />

<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" id="statusbar" modal="true"
    showEffect="fade" showHeader="false" closable="false" width="250"
    resizable="false">
<h:form>
  <center>
    <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/loading.gif" /><br />
    <b>Please wait...</b><br />
    <br />
  </center>
</h:form>
```